# SetWindowsHook Global not very Global

Tags: winapi, global, setwindowshookex

I'm playing around with SetWindowsHookEx, specifically I would like be able to find out about *any* window (on my desktop) thats been activated, via mouse or keyboard.

Reading through MSDN docs for SetWindowsHookEx it would appear that a WH_CBT type would do the job. I've created a dll and put all the code in there, which I control from a gui app (which also handles the unhook).

BUT I only appear to be getting the activation code when I activate my gui app though, any other app I activate is ignored.

In my dll I have the setup code and the CBTProc like so:

```
LRESULT WINAPI CBTProc(int Code, WPARAM W, LPARAM L) {
   if(Code<0) CallN....

   if (Code == HCBT_ACTIVATE) { // never get unless I activate my app
      HWND a = reinterpret_cast<HWND>(W);
      TRACE("this window was activated %d\n", a);
   }

   CallNext....
}

EXPORTED HHOOK WINAPI Setup(HWND MyWind) {
   ...
   // gDllUInstance set in dllmain
   return SetWindowsHookEx(WH_CBT, CBTProc, gDllUInstance, 0);
}
```

All pretty simple stuff, i've tried moving the setup out of the dll but I still get the same effect.

It would appear that the dll is getting loaded into other processes, I'm counting the number of DLL_PROCESS_ATTACHs I'm getting and can see its going up (not very scientific i know.

NOTE that this is 32 bit code running on 32bit OS - win2k3.

Are my expectations of the hooking mechanism wrong? should I only be getting the activation of my app or do I need a different type of hook?

EDIT: the trace function writes to a file telling me whats sending me activations

TIA.

Comment: It isn't clear what your TRACE macro does.  It is however likely that you just can't see its side-effects since it runs in another process.

Comment: In particular, it may be logging to a file in a directory different from the one you're expecting.

Comment: Does TRACE close the handle of the file that you are writing to? You may be having concurrency issues due to different processes not being able to acquire the write lock.

Comment: Doesn't CBTProc have to be exported as well?

Comment: @Joel Lucsy: No since it's passed as a function pointer. No need to do any dynamic linking.

Comment: It may be easier to use [SetWinEventHook(EVENT_SYSTEM_FOREGROUND, ... , WINEVENT_OUTOFCONTEXT)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd373640(v=vs.85).aspx) instead; this allows the callback to take place in your own process, which is easier to manage and debug, and works for both 32-bit and 64-bit processes.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out its working ok, as Hans points out, i'm just not seeing the output from the debugger from the other processes, if I put in some extra tracing code - one trace file per attached process - I can see can see that things are working after all.

Many thanks for the replies.